# Manipulate win10 speech recognition behaviour

Tags: windows-10, windows-speech-recognition

Is it possible to somehow manipulate win10 speech recognition behaviour? I have to use due to tendinits symptoms. What would already help a lot would be if I say "click", that this is always recorded as a command to left click the mouse. Sometimes it is recorded as text.

Comment: Buy a good microphone. Same advice since 1989.

Comment: it is not that it doesnt understand me, I would just like to customize commands...